# Find closest datapoint to a date in another dataframe

Tags: r, data-science

I have two data frames. One data frame is called `Measurements` and has 500 rows. The columns are `PatientID`, `Value` and `M_Date`. The other data frame is called `Patients` and has 80 rows and the columns are `PatientID`, `P_Date`.

Each patient ID in Patients is **unique**. For each row in `Patients`, I want to look at the set of measurements in `Measurements` with the same `PatientID` (there are maybe 6-7 per patient).

From this set of measurements, I want to identify the one with `M_Date` closest to `P_Date`. I want to append this value to `Patients` in a new column. How do I do this? I tried using `ddplyr` but can't figure out how to access two data frames at once within this function.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example and provide some sample data using `head(dput())`

Comment: you can use `merge` and filter based on `rank`

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to install the `install.packages("survival")` and the `neardate` function within it to solve your problem.
It has a good example in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survival/versions/2.42-3/topics/neardate)